# Скомкано или скомканно?

Tags: причастия, наречия, прилагательные

**Скомкано**― везде в Интернете; корректор настаивает на **скомканно**.
А как правильно?

Answer (score 8):

Нужен контекст.

Краткое причастие:

*Всё было скомкано и выброшено.*

Краткое прилагательное:

*Выступление скомканно и непонятно, его трудно записывать.*

Наречие:

*Мероприятие прошло скомканно (от причастия скомканный).*

Comment: «...учитывая суровые реалии того, что мы имеем и с чем работаем, мы просто физически не можем это сделать. Это будет скомкано и некорректно...»

Comment: В сочетании с "некорректно" это наречие, поэтому вас поправили.

Comment: Это будет скомканно и некорректно. Краткое прилагательное (каково?). Обычно при однородных отношениях с другими прилагательными.

Comment: P.S. Сравните: это (мероприятие) будет скомкано и испорчено окончательно.

Comment: @Sibylla Да, в этом конкретном случае (при глаголе "быть") правильнее именовать слово кратким прилагательным (вопрос это выявляет), а не наречием (как при прочих глаголах); к счастью, это различие не отражается на написании.

Answer (score 3):

Скомканный ― причастие, скомканно ― наречие, скомкано ― краткое причастие, скомканно - краткое отпричастное прилагательное, все эти формы надо различать.

**1) Наречие**

Затем ему, видимо, стало совсем неловко; он **скомканно** попрощался и положил трубку. [Дина Рубина. Медная шкатулка (сборник) (2015)]

Проговорил он с набитым ртом, поэтому его слова прозвучали **скомканно** и невнятно. [Н. Леонов, А. Макеев. Эхо дефолта (2000-2004)]

**2) Краткое причастие**

Лицо его было **скомкано** морщинами, а из щелочек глаз подозрительно смотрели явно безумные зрачки. [Михаил Гиголашвили. Чертово колесо (2007)] У меня здесь все **скомкано**: пересказ.  [Г. Я. Бакланов. Разное // «Знамя», 2002]

**3) Краткое опричастное прилгательное (каково?)**

И Мовчуну вдруг стало ясно, что репетиция испорчена, все будет **скомканно и нервно** ― как этот вечер неудачно начался, так и закончится под утро неудачно. [Андрей Дмитриев. Призрак театра (2002-2003) // «Знамя», 2003]

Answer (score 0):

Это две разных части речи: (нечто было) скомка**н**о - краткое страдательное причастие; (как?) скомка**нн**о - наречие, образованное от прилагательного "скомканный".

> Оратор говорил скомка**нн**о, пропуская куски заготовленной речи.
>
> В записи на телевидении выступление министра было скомка**н**о и длилось 2
>   минуты.